# Set Environment Variable on CENTOS 7

Tags: environment-variables

I want to add to the global PATH variable for CENTOS 7. I've created a script that does the following:

PATH = /usr/dir1/bin:/usr/dir1/lib:$PATH
export $PATH

The above script has been added to the directory "/etc/profile.d" as my-script.sh. I've also changed it to execute using the following command: "chmod 755 my-script.sh"

However, when I execute the command:

echo $PATH

I don't see that my additional paths have been added to the path variable.

What I'm I doing wrong?

Thanks